# Lookup all cells of one row in another df and return flag if all exist using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, row, lookup

there are two dataframes A and B,  df A like below including main nodes and their depends against each node:

```
 NODE          Depend
=====   =============================
T1234   T1235   T1236   T1237   T1238
-------------------------------------
B1234   B1235   B1236   B1237   B1238
-------------------------------------
N1234   N1235   N1236   N1237   N1238
-------------------------------------
```

I wanna lookup each rows from df A in df B to find out are they all available in the df B or not.

```
Node
=====
T1234
T1235
T1236
T1237
T1238
B1234
B1235
B1238
N1234
N1237
```

if all cells in one row including the main node of df A are available in the df B then return True flag else return False in df A as a new column like below:

```
 NODE          Depend                 flag
=====   ============================= =====
T1234   T1235   T1236   T1237   T1238   T
-------------------------------------------
B1234   B1235   B1236   B1237   B1238   F
-------------------------------------------
N1234   N1235   N1236   N1237   N1238   F
-------------------------------------------
```

what is the most efficient way to do this via pandas? i tried many ways like merging two df but found no way to can compare whole one row to lookup in the df B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make `dfA` comma separated. Derive a `list` of column `Depend`.Derive a list of `dfB`. Compare the `lists` using `sets` and use `np.where (condition, True if Condition, False if condition)`. where condition here is that the length of what is common between the `lists` should be equal to `four` or juts more than `3`.

```
print(dfA)#Separated by comma


  NODE                   Depend
0  T1234  T1235,T1236,T1237,T1238
1  B1234  B1235,B1236,B1237,B1238
2  N1234  N1235,N1236,N1237,N1238

s=list(dfB.Node.values.tolist())#dfB into a list
dfA.Depend=dfA.Depend.str.split(',')#dfA.Depend into a list


dfA['flag']=np.where(dfA.Depend.apply(lambda x:len([*{*x}&{*s}])>3), 'T','F')
print(dfA)



NODE                        Depend    flag
0  T1234  [T1235, T1236, T1237, T1238]    T
1  B1234  [B1235, B1236, B1237, B1238]    F
2  N1234  [N1235, N1236, N1237, N1238]    F
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way.  I created dummy column labels for the first data frame:

```
# the first data frame
print(df_A)
         d-1    d-2    d-3    d-4
Node                             
T1234  T1235  T1236  T1237  T1238
B1234  B1235  B1236  B1237  B1238
N1234  N1235  N1236  N1237  N1238
```

```
# the second data frame
print(df_B)
0    T1234
1    T1235
2    T1236
3    T1237
4    T1238
5    B1234
6    B1235
7    B1238
8    N1234
9    N1237
Name: Node, dtype: object
```

Check each *row* of A against B:

```
df_A['flag'] = df_A.apply(lambda x: x.isin(df_B).all(), axis=1)
print(df_A)

         d-1    d-2    d-3    d-4   flag
Node                                    
T1234  T1235  T1236  T1237  T1238   True
B1234  B1235  B1236  B1237  B1238  False
N1234  N1235  N1236  N1237  N1238  False
```